# HTML & JavaScript Code working on Online HTML Editor but not on local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to create a select menu that allows the user to choose one option whether by typing or selecting it from the list. The code is working on online editors such as (JSfiddle). The issue is that select list doesn't work as expected when I try opening it up on my local machine using Chrome or Firefox.

Here is the HTML code that I'm using on online editors (select.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />

  <div id="select-container">
  <select id="test" style="width:150px">
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
      <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5">Option 5</option>
      <option value="6">Option 6</option>
      <option value="6.1">Option 6.1</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just added the following line on my local machine inside HTML body to load the JS file:

```
<script src="select.js"></script>
```

And here is my JS code (select.js):

```
/* jshint esnext: true */
$("#test").select2();

optgroupState = {};

$("body").on('click', '.select2-container--open .select2-results__group', function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggle();
  id = $(this).closest('.select2-results__options').attr('id');
  index = $('.select2-results__group').index(this);
  optgroupState[id][index] = !optgroupState[id][index];
});

$('#test').on('select2:open', function() {
  $('.select2-dropdown--below').css('opacity', 0);
  setTimeout(() => {
    groups = $('.select2-container--open .select2-results__group');
    id = $('.select2-results__options').attr('id');
    if (!optgroupState[id]) {
      optgroupState[id] = {};
    }
    $.each(groups, (index, v) => {
      optgroupState[id][index] = optgroupState[id][index] || false;
      optgroupState[id][index] ? $(v).siblings().show() : $(v).siblings().hide(); 
    });
    $('.select2-dropdown--below').css('opacity', 1);
  }, 0);
});
```

[That's what I'm getting on my online editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8FLd.png)
However, I'm getting a normal list that displays all the options straight away on my local machine and has no text box for user input.

Any suggests would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look in the Network panel of dev tools to ensure script is being loaded. Or add a `console.log('test 123')` to the top of the script. Its also possible that the code is being run before jQuery is loaded

Comment: How about Chrome or Firefox console errors?

Comment: Yeah its printing out "test 123" inside the console which means it linked correctly.
and no console errors

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: Try placing the `<script src="select.js"></script>` just before closing of body tag.

Comment: What are you expecting? You failed to mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your script after document loads in select.js. Also, Check your config on jsfiddle on how the script is run.

Enclose your js code as below.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /* your entire js code goes here */
});
```

Comment: Its working now after enclosing it with what you provided. :)
I tried that before but without the semicolon at the end.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check the file path in `<script src="select.js"></script>`. May be select.js and your html file are not in same folder.

Comment: Yeah I did check that and printed a message to the log and it was outputted on the console